# The cricket questions here are pretty good

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, site-evaluation

Looking over the site (and the most recent evaluations) I'm struck with the quality of questions and answers in the [cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cricket) tag.  Scanning the [Greatest Hits](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) shows a fair number of cricket questions as well.  Doing the exercise where I try to find answers to sample questions via Google, the cricket questions do well and the other questions do poorly.

My question is why and what can we do to improve the questions and answers about other sports?

Comment: Get more users who are as versed as the cricket users in other sports? A user asked what seemed to be a large number of cricket questions, and before you know it, a [community of cricket users](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/363/527) develops on an interdisciplinary site. If the same thing happens for other sports, the same thing will happen. Demographics also play a role...

Answer (score 5):

I do have a *few* ideas:

1. The field for cricket sites on the internet is not as crowded as for other sports.  Therefore, it's easier for Google to land on Sports.SE for those questions than it would be for questions about, say baseball.  So knowledgable cricket fans find answers to their questions on this site and stick around to answer more.  Hence, a positive feedback loop.
2. Other sports, such as Olympic events, tennis, and international football seem to do better than average.  Again, I suspect the relative lack of competition in those topics plays a part.
3. This site is a bit like the [Wide World of Sports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_World_of_Sports_%28U.S._TV_series%29) show.  There are plenty of outlets on the internet for baseball, American football, and basketball, but not so many for rugby, skateboarding, and volleyball.
4. Lot's of questions here focus on explaining rules and analysing why events turned out the way they did.  If the sport get's lots of exposure on ESPN, it's likely some analyst (or 10) have beaten that horse well past the grave.  On the other hand, "fringe" sports could really use a place where such questions can be pondered and, hopefully, answered.
5. Titles on the site could use some work. The last review featured a couple of questions that sounded general, but turned out to be about a very specific situation.  Looking at the main page, I don't see any examples of what I'm talking about, so it might have been a sampling problem.  In any case, the cricket question did not seem to have that problem.  (Perhaps because they tend to be more general?)

Those thoughts turned out a little random.  Feel free to pitch in your own answers.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion: "striking the iron while it's hot."

See [How does one get 5 points in a football game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3208/how-does-one-get-5-points-in-a-football-game) This was a very recent event including two new users.

This question received a quick response, and both the question and answer received upvotes quicker than usual.

Comment: An excellent point.  Searching the internet, the answer is on-par or slightly better than other explanations.  [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp#pws=0&q=football+%225+points%22&safe=active) has already picked up our Q&A. So in addition to getting someone their answer quickly, it will also help people long-term and introduce more folks to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Let's face some hard facts here. [Stackexchange network's traffic comes mostly from the USA and the next biggest provider is India](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com#trafficstats). Here is lies the problem. India and the surrounding areas, are crazy about Cricket. So lots of Indian public here come and ask about cricket a lot. Again, this is also a fact that Cricket is not so popular out of Indian subcontinent. But visitors from other parts of the world are not increasing. So cricket questions are dominating this site.

Comment: Absolutely.  The UK is up there too and folks over there have had an interest in cricket as well.  I wouldn't say this is a problem (far from it).  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @JonEricson, Hmm UK's presence is also significant. By _problem_, I tired to mean that I wish this site does not eventually become **Cricket Stackexchange** from our favourite **Sports Stackexchange** (_Although I am too a cricket fan_)

Comment: This is a point that supports my "demographic" comment.

Answer (score 1):

For the [badminton](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badminton) tag, I'm having the problem that the terminology used in badminton, often is explained on the internet, although many times on fora and/or (poor) badminton fan sites.

Should I throw in easy questions?

Comment: If the answers to your easy questions are not available on other sites or are difficult to find, that seems like a good idea to me.  Ideally, since the questions are simple, you would [self-answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) them.  Just a reminder: it's probably best to ask only one or two at a time so that the front page doesn't look like we should rename the site to badminton.SE. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson My proposal to do so on Area 51, was being closed pretty quickly =) The problem is that people search the internet to find the answer. I want people who play the game to answer my question and not people who play a game with a bat and know how to perform a search more or less.

Comment: @JonEricson Where have you been? We have had [not 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2433?m=9160494#9160494) mention about cricket...[not 2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9160856#9160856), [not 3](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9161038#9161038), [not 4](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9162162#9162162), [not 5](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2433?m=9335564#9335564), [not 6](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9165783#9165783)...[not 7](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2433?m=7309108#7309108)...

Comment: @JonEricson In all honesty, this question would have been relevant [several months ago](http://i.imgur.com/SrCHCFN.jpg) when the front page was worthy of renaming the site to Cricket.SE :D